# Arquivos do Projeto ASP .NET MVC não abrem "the operation could not be completed"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Tento abrir arquivos "cshtml" e o mesmo não abre, apresentando o erro abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso ocorre em todos os meus projetos, começou de uma hora para outra.

Utilizo o Visual Studio 2015, projeto ASP .NET 4.6 MVC 5.
Quem puder ajudar agradeço.

Como solicitado segue o codigo do Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>


<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-palmasjudoclube.com.br.web-20140225031045.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-palmasjudoclube.com.br.web-20140225031045;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Efetuei a exclusão de uma classe cshtml do projeto e o Visual Studio conseguiu abrir o arquivo, porem o mesmo apresenta a mensagem de exeção abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O conteúdo do arquivo analisei e nao encontrei nenhum erro de chaves ou repetição. Tentei inserir o conteúdo do mesmo porem ultrapassa os limite de 30000 caracteres de uma pergunta.
Estou pensando seriamente em excluir o Visual Studio e reinstalar o mesmo.

Comment: Veja se isso não pode lhe ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523510/vs2013-operation-could-not-be-completed

Comment: Tente procurar por erros nos web.config, tanto no do projeto como do das views, procurando por erros de tags duplicadas ou espaços em lugares incorretos

Comment: Pode por favor colocar o conteúdo dos seus arquivos `Web.config` na sua pergunta?

Comment: Coloquei ai WebConfig. 
O detalhe é que isso ocorre em todos os projetos, ate mesmo em novos.
Não consigo perceber qual seria o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi restaurando o Visual Studio, pois o fato ocorria em qualquer projeto não se conseguia abrir uma arquivo cshtml, sendo que abria em outros editores e somente no Visual Studio que não abria.
Restaurando resolvi.